# Good reference book for digital image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I am learning digital image processing on my own and would like recomendations on good reference books.  If you know of books to definately stay away from that would be useful as well.

Thanks

Comment: I was looking into writing my own Photoshop type libraries to get familiar with the subject.  I was planning on using them on the many less than perfect pictures I have taken of my family.  Later on I wanted to learn some facial recognition algorithms in order to autoclassify / caption the images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Digital Image Processing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/DIP-3E/dip3e_main_page.htm) (!) by Gonzalez & Woods is pretty much *the* classic.

Answer (score 1):

I used Gonzalez and Woods in my coursework, and it covers image restoration, which you say is your main interest. [''Fundamentals of Digital Image Processing''](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133361659) by Jain takes a more mathematical/statistical approach and covers some different topics, but I haven't gone through the whole thing. I'd guess it'd be useful if statistics are your thing.

Probably easier would be to use Photoshop, the GIMP, or similar instead of reinventing the wheel. They can be used in batch mode in some circumstances, and you can write plugins if there's something special you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Al Bovik - The Essential Guide to Image Processing

William Pratt -  Digital Image Processing

Bernd Jahne - Digital Image Processing

All of them are great, at least as good as "Digital Image Processing".