# Image-Procssing Books

Tags: image-processing

I'm a newbie to Image-processing thing and  I want to read a book that is good to start with.I've searched online for books but when I start to read  them I can't really get the idea , so any suggestions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764713/good-reference-book-for-digital-image-processing/2105192#2105192

Comment: Dwayne Phillips' book *Image Processing in C*... http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Digital Image Processing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/)
by Gonzalez and Woods is a standard reference.